# I want to get filtered row in dataframe by word but it gives blank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter, tweepy

I want to get filtered row in my dataframe by word. My word is Doge. Dataframe includes Elon Musk tweets. I want to filter by word these tweets and pull the filtered tweet. Last part of my code algorithm is below.

```
pi = tweepy.API(authenticate, wait_on_rate_limit = True)
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = "elonmusk", count = 2000,lang = "en", tweet_mode = "extended")

df = pd.DataFrame([tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets], columns = ["tweet"])
def cleantext(text):
    text = re.sub(r'@\w+', "", text) # Remove Mentions
    text = re.sub(r"#", "", text) # Remove Hashtags Symbol
    text = re.sub(r"RT[\s]+", "", text) # Remove Retweets
    text = re.sub(r"https?:\/\/\S+", "", text) # Remove The Hyper Link
    
    return text
# Clean The Text
df["tweet"] = df["tweet"].apply(cleantext)

df[df['tweet'].str.contains('Doge')]
```

Comment: Please provide the data as text.

Comment: which data is provided text?

Comment: Provide the output of `df.to_dict()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
#make a dataframe 
d = {'tweet': ['elon tweets about doge coin', 'elon tweets about bitcoin']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#get filtered records for twwets containing doge
df.loc[df['tweet'].str.contains('doge'),:]
```

This is what it looks like in my enviroment
[image]

you can use df.loc to filter both columns and records from a dataframe, in this case we are filtering the records by a string that contains doge.

the documentation is here if you wan to take a look:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Answer (score 1):

Try case insensitive with:

```
df[df['tweet'].str.contains(r'(?i)Doge', regex=True)]
```